# Centering menu items in a 100% width CSS drop down menu

Tags: css

I'm extremely new to CSS--I'm talking I just started learning it yesterday.  Anyways, I have a 100% width drop down menu bar that I want to have the contents(links) centered in the menu.  I've Googled all day and tried many different things, but can't seem to figure it out.  Here's my CSS:

```
.menu{
border:none;
text-align:center;
border:0px;
margin:0px;
width:100%;
padding:0px;
font: 67.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;

}
.menu ul{
background:#333333;
height:35px;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}
.menu li{
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    }
.menu li a{
    background:#333333 url(seperatornew.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
    color:#cccccc;
    display:block;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:35px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 25px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    .menu li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover a{
        background: #c20000 url("hovernew.gif") bottom center no-repeat;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
.menu li ul{
    background:#333333;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:225px;
    z-index:200;
    /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/
    }
.menu li:hover ul{
    display:block;

    }
.menu li li {
    background:url('sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:225px;
    }
.menu li:hover li a{
    background:none;

    }
.menu li ul a{
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:normal;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align:left;
    }
    .menu li ul a:hover, .menu li ul li:hover a{
        background:#c20000 url('hover_subnew.gif') center left no-repeat;
        border:0px;
        color:#ffffff;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
.menu p{
    clear:left;
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/htm/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<style>
body {margin:0}
}</style>
</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<center><img alt="" src="Banner2011New.gif"></center>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu_style2.css">
<div class="menu">
<style type="text/css">

 a:link {

 COLOR: #ffffff;

 }
 a:visited {
 COLOR: #ffffff;
 }</style>
<ul>
<li><a target="_self" href="home2.htm">Home</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="viewlistings.htm">View Listings</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="aboutus2.htm">About Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a target="_self" href="judybio2.htm">Judy's Bio</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="stevebio2.htm">Steve's Bio</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="blakebio2.htm">Blake's Bio</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="mavbio2.htm">Maverick's Bio</a></li></ul></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="contact2.htm">Contact Info</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="emailus2.htm">E-Mail Us</a>
<ul>
<li><a target="_self" href="emailjudy.htm">E-Mail Judy</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="emailsteve.htm">E-Mail Steve</a></li>
<li><a target="_self" href="emailblake.htm">E-Mail Blake</a></li></ul></li></ul></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<center>&nbsp;</center>
</body>
</html>
```

A live example of the menu that I'm working with can be found at: www.judyandsteve.com/test.htm

Thanks!

Comment: `<center>`? I think learning CSS is a bit overdue :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### CSS

```
.menu ul {
   text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   #display: inline;
   zoom: 1;
   text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: @Blake S Feel free to give me the green tick :D